# How to see sinusoidal wave from SPWM output?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, circuit-design, power-electronics, stm32f4

I am generating SPWM waveforms using complementary outputs of advance timer. I wonder how can i see the actual sinusoidal waveform on an oscilloscope which is intended from the SPWM output? My MCU is STM32F407VG.

Comment: Simple R/C low pass filter between PWM output and oscilloscope probe?

Comment: So will the PWM pin will directly drive the RC-LPF or do i need to buffer it?

Comment: The R from the R/C consists of the resistor you use (let's call that Ru) and the internal resistance Ri of the source: R = Ri + Ru. By using a buffer what are doing is changing the Ri of your source. Thus when you add a buffer you need a different Ru. You probably do not know the Ri. Thus the method I would use is start with assuming Ri is zero and calculate an R/C. Try it and see if you need to change R and/or C. It is called "Trial and error".

Comment: Since the oscilloscope should have a very high input impedance (MegaOhm) you can also use a large resistor in your R/C filter. Haven't looked into the datasheet of the STM32F407 but IIRC its digital pins should be able to source/sink about 3mA. At 3.3V that's 1.1kOhm of permissible load resistance. Take some resistor you have at hand from the 10-100kOhm range, calculate the capacitance you need for that and the frequency you want and you're good to go.

Comment: Hint: The "frequency you want" is the "cut-off" frequency of the LPF, which you want to be somewhere between the PWM frequency and the frequency of the sinusoidal signal. The lower it is the less PWM 'noise' will be in the filtered signal, but your signal's amplitude will be lower because the signal's frequency will begin to be filtered out. A higher cut-off frequency means less reduction at the signal's frequency but more of the higher frequency PWM noise will get through.